# How many three-digit numbers can be formed from the given set if each digit can occur only once? Of these, how many are even?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A) How many three digit numbers from $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ can be created?

I answered this by $9 \times 8 \times 7 = 504$. The possible answers are 84 - 450 - 504 - 729

B) How many of those numbers are odd?

Possible answers are 42 - 405 - 280 - 225

I tried answering this with $9 \times 8 \times 5$ (since it should end with an odd number and there are $5$ of those in the offered numbers). However, it is not correct.

EDIT: I forgot to add that every number can only occur once.

Suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why 9x8x5 in a) ? and not just 9x9x9 ? Similarly in b)? Why not just 9x9x5?. My question is, why u came up with an idea to descrease number of choices on the second and third "place"

Comment: An integer that is not even is said to be *odd*.

Comment: With the added condition, your first answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every number can be used once , you must select first the unit cipher and you have $5$ choices, then you have only $8$ choices and then $7$, so the answer is:

$$5\times 8 \times 7=280$$

:)